# symfony send form request without submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony

I want to send request using just choice type, and without submit button, i tried with javascript but no result

My form code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
   ->add('language', 'choice', array(
       'choices' => array(
             'ar' => 'Arabic',
             'fr' => 'French',
             'es' => 'Espagnol',
             'nl' => 'Dutch',
             'ja' => 'Japanese',
             'en' => 'English',
             'ko' => 'Korean',
             'it' => 'Italian',
             'ru' => 'Russian',
       ),
       'required'    => false,
       'placeholder' => 'Click to Choose Language..',
       'attr' => array(
                   'id' => 'field',
                   'class' => 'controls',
                   'data-rel' => 'chosen'
                )
  ))
  ->getForm();
```

My twig is as follows:

```
<form  action="{{ path('test_test') }}"  method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
          {{ form_widget(form.language, { 'attr': {'class': 'select2'} }) }}
</form>
```

The javascript  code that i used is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#field').change(function() {
       $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: can you check if the change event is fired

Comment: Are you using select2 plugin ? (https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: ok see my edit in my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $(".select2").change(function() { //put class or id of your select input
      $('#id_of_your_form').submit();
   });
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using select2 plugin (you have examples [here](http://code.runnable.com/UmuP-67-dQlIAAFU/events-in-select2-for-jquery)) :

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $('.select2').select2()
     .on("change", function(e) {
          $('#id_of_your_form').submit();
     })
});
```

And then you can get POST data sending in your Symfony Controller like this :

```
public function getDataAction(Request $request)
{
   dump($request->request->get('name of your select input');exit;
}
```

Comment: I tested that , no result either, the form if , can i add it like that  <form id="formlang">  ??

Comment: yes you can and then change jquery selector by this

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(function($) {
   $(".select2").change(function() {
      $('#formlang').submit();
   });
       });
    </script>     it's not working

Comment: Has your select input `.select2` class ?

Comment: {{ form_widget(form.language, { 'attr': {'class': 'select2'} }) }}

Comment: yes but when you inspect your html in your browser you see it ?

Comment: it's not sending the request soo ?

Comment: I edit my answer as you use select2 plugin you can see it :)